# has_many_association multiple queries making it slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am having has_many_association table. For an e.g. User has_many subscriptions. On index page of active admin, i am showing multiple calculated fields for which i require to call user.subscriptions.last. Since i am calling it multiple times. So due to this our server is getting overloaded. It was handled on index page as it is showing only 30 entries there. But while exporting to CSV our server get overloaded due to multiple queries. I am using approximately 15 queries for one user.

The problem here is i have to check for valid subscription for printing its code. Also i cannot put where query in scoped_collection because it will only load the data of the user for valid subscriptions. So how to solve this problem???????

```
def scoped_collection
  end_of_association_chain.includes(:subscriptions, :blogs)
end
index do  
  column :email
  column "referrer" do |user|
    subscription = user.subscriptions.valid.first
    subscription.referrers.first.code if subscription
  end
  column "blog_id" do |user|
     user.blog.id if user.blog
  end

end
```

User has_many subscriptions and subscription has_many referrers i want first referrer code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this lines to your users.rb file

```
 controller do
      def scoped_collection
        # Method 1  
        super.includes(subscriptions: :referrers) # prevents N+1 queries to your database
        # method 2
        User.includes(subscriptions: :referrers).select("users.*, (SELECT referrers.code from referrers LIMIT 1) as refer_code")
      end
  end
```

Comment: I am already using this piece of code def scoped_collection
      end_of_association_chain.where(:origin => 1).includes(:subscriptions, :blogs)
    end

Comment: You said you use 15 queries for one user, reduce that query. please add code of users.rb. , also add association an schema.rb which required

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, i have again gone through the queries it is making. The problem is the nested has_many_association. subscription has_many referrers, so it is executing query for this. So how to skip these queries. Thanks

Comment: it will be easy for me if you add actual code of file. and related associations

Comment: I have added the partial code.. now you can check if you need anything else let me know. Thanks

Comment: @SumitSharma updated my answer, please check let me know if its working or not

Comment: glad to know that :)

Comment: @SumitSharma I added one more query, if you just want to load only `code`  field from referrers table. you can select only that one. by this query, you can access code by `refer_code` attribute.

Comment: I have updated my question and code, i am facing one more issue.

Comment: @SumitSharma you should ask new question, as you are facing another issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52178885/has-many-association-sate-check-executing-n1-queries-active-admin. please answer this question

Answer (score 0):

In your controller call `@subscriptions = current_user.subscriptions`

And then in your views call `@subscriptions.last` wherever needed, and no new query will called in the views as the records will already be loaded in the controller.

Comment: That problem is solved. Now the problem is caused due to nested has_many_associations. subscription has_many referrers, so it is executing query for this. So how to skip these queries. Thanks

Comment: Try doing `@subscriptions = current_user.subscriptions.includes(:referrers)`
It wont execute queries if you call the referrers through subscriptions, eg. `@subscriptions.last.referrers`

Comment: @haseeb, no need to call .all method as current_user.subscriptions will give you the same.

Comment: @MohdAnas Yes you're right. Removed it from my answer.

Comment: I have updated my question and code, i am facing one more issue.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve All Field:

```
controller do
  def scoped_collection
    Model.all.as_json(include: [:subscriptions,:referrers])
    # prevents N+1 queries to your database
  end
end
```

Retrieve Some field like:

```
controller do
   def scoped_collection
     Model.all.as_json(include: [:subscriptions => {only: :field1}])                                       
   end
 end
```