# has_many association sate check executing N+1 queries active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Model Strucure: User has many subscriptions and blogs , Subscriptions has_many coupons.
I have included the has_many table but i need to perform state check for every subscription 
  So if i perform where query in scoped collection than it gets all the user only having valid subscriptions. So how to avoid N+1 query and also perform state check.

```
def scoped_collection
  end_of_association_chain.includes(:subscriptions, :blogs)
end
index do  
  column :email
  column "referrer" do |user|
    subscription = user.subscriptions.valid.first
    subscription.referrers.first.code if subscription
  end
  column "blog_id" do |user|
     user.blog.id if user.blog
  end

end
```

Comment: what is subscription.valid ?

Comment: Subscription.where(:state => 1)

Comment: Please check my answer, let me know if its not working

Comment: @Vishal It is not working, reason i have mentioned in comment please check

Answer (score 1):

A common way to increase page performance is to eliminate N+1 queries by eager loading associations:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  includes :author, :categories
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Load valid subscriptions from query only, please check below code

```
 controller do
      def scoped_collection
        User.includes(subscriptions: :referrers).select("users.*, (SELECT referrers.code from referrers WHERE subscriptions.state = 1 LIMIT 1) as refer_code")
      end
  end
```

Comment: I cannot use it for only referrer code, because i have many more columns, So i just need valid subscriptions. Also i have modified as select("users.*, (SELECT * from subscriptions WHERE subscriptions.state = 1)")  But it not working.. please help me out

Comment: @SumitSharma Yes, it will only pick up valid subscriptions , can you please show me which error you get ?

Comment: here is the error Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s): SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  users.*, (SELECT * from subscriptions WHERE subscriptions.state = 1) AS count_column FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`origin` = 20 LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count

Comment: Try my query only, why you are using LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0, just use LIMIT 1, this is sub query and it will not apply on whole records. change to LIMIT 1 and check records

Comment: @SumitSharma use gem 'pry' for debugging , and add `binding.pry` after the query @users.map(&:attributes) will give you alll attributes

Comment: @users.map(&:attributes) is giving all users attributes. It will be very helpful if you could modify the query so that i can get all users and only valid subscriptions with that

Comment: in @users you will get all attributes of users table with `refer_code` code, which we added through query, do you get that attribute ?